# Use Conditional Formatting formula to check if cell is blank with Office Js

Tags: office-js

I have recently started using Office js .I am trying to implement the formula ISBLANK() to check if a cell is blank using office js. There are examples of conditional formatting with CellValue,ColorScale,PresetCriteria etc.
For e.g.

```
var conditionalFormat = range.conditionalFormats.add(Excel.ConditionalFormatType.containsText);
conditionalFormat.textComparison.format.fill.color = "red";
conditionalFormat.textComparison.rule = { operator:Excel.ConditionalTextOperator.beginsWith, text: "Test" }
```

The above code is highlighting those cells which contains the word "Test" in a selected range.
But I am not getting any example anywhere to create a rule using a formula .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use formulas for conditional formatting you want to use the [Custom Conditional Format type.](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/excel/customconditionalformat)

Here's a sample:

```
var sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
var range = sheet.getRange("A1:A5");
range.values = [[1], [20], [""], [5], ["foo"]];

var cf = range.conditionalFormats.add(Excel.ConditionalFormatType.custom);
var cfCustom = cf.customOrNullObject;
cfCustom.rule.formula = "=ISBLANK(A1)";
cfCustom.format.fill.color = "#00FF00";

await context.sync();
```

For your convenience, here's a [gist you can import directly into ScriptLab](https://gist.github.com/prueker/31e584b829aebe86377244d43384ccbf).

-Philip, Software Engineer on the Office Developer Team

Comment: I have another query related to conditional formatting. Is there any way in Office js to check if the condition of a particula conditional format is met?   For above Example , I want to disable the submit button of my app if any cell under the conditional format is blank.

Comment: @b.sa - could you please mark the answer as accepted, so that other users will benefit from seeing that your question was answered. 
As to your follow up question, no this isn't possible, you would have to manually check the cell contents. 
We may add functionality to find special cells such as blank cells in the future, but right now our APIs do not support this.